# How to detect the end of a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm writting a recursive function that use specific formulas to calculate 2 lists.
But I will simplify the function so you can understand the problem I'm having because the point here is to detect [] of the list.

So I've the following code:

```
listSum::([Integer],[Integer])->Double
listSum ((x:xs),(y:ys)) 
    | ((x:xs),(y:ys))==(x:[],y:[])=0.0
    | otherwise = (((fromIntegral x)::Double)+((fromIntegral y)::Double)) + listSum ((xs),(ys))
```

Output I'm having right now

```
listSum([1,2],[1,2])
2.0

listSum([1],[1])
0.0

listSum([],[])
*** Exception: file.hs: .....: Non-exhaustive patterns in function ListSum
```

And the output I wish to have

```
listSum([1,2],[1,2])
6.0

listSum([1],[1])
2.0

listSum([],[])
0.0
```

What did I miss? Or did I write too much?

Comment: you detect the end of a list by pattern-matching on `[]` (e.g. `myFunc [] = 0; myFunc (x:xs) = x + myFunc xs`)

Comment: The first thing to do is to tell GHC `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the first guard in your function. You can simply write it as the following (I just dropped `::Double` because Haskell can infer it)

```
listSum :: ([Integer], [Integer]) -> Double
listSum ([], []) = 0.0
listSum ((x:xs),(y:ys)) = fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y + listSum (xs, ys)
```

Now, whenever the arguments passed to `listSum` are empty lists, the result will be `0.0`, otherwise the recursive function will be called.

**Note:** The above function will work only if both the lists are of equal size. Otherwise, you need to write it like this

```
listSum::([Integer],[Integer])->Double
listSum ([], []) = 0.0
listSum ((x:xs), []) = fromIntegral x + listSum(xs, [])
listSum ([], (y:ys)) = fromIntegral y + listSum(ys, [])
listSum ((x:xs),(y:ys)) = fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y + listSum (xs, ys)
```

**Note:** Even simpler, the entire code can be written, [as suggested by Rein Henrichs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642569/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-list-in-haskell/28642600?noredirect=1#comment45584135_28642600), like this

```
pairwiseSum xs ys = sum (zipWith (+) xs ys)
```

Comment: This still has incomplete patterns!

Comment: @dfeuer I think in OP's case both the lists will be of equal size.

Comment: Yes, in my case, both lists are equal size.

Thank you thefourtheye, really nice explanation. It works.

Comment: @dfeuer Okay, I am missing something then. Can you please give an example?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I just mean that incomplete patterns are bad, even if you think they'll never cause a problem. May I suggest you nix all the `::Double` annotations? GHC can infer all those by itself.

Comment: As an alternative solution that handles lists of unequal size in a reasonable way, `pairwiseSum xs ys = sum (zipWith (+) xs ys)`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Thanks :-) Included that suggestion in the answer.

Comment: (or just `pairwiseSum = (sum .) . zipWith (+)`)

Comment: @Dogbert I specifically avoided that pointfree version because it reduces readability for no gain. It's a perfect example of pointless pointfree.